# Largest Source Of Students

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am not sure about the meaning of the adjective "large" (or its superlative form) here:

> [link](http://www.enz.govt.nz/markets-research/china)
>   China is the world’s ***largest*** source of international students, but the rate of growth in outbound students is slowing.

Does "*largest*" refer to the physical size of China?

Answer (score 2):

No, it means that more Chinese students study in other countries (as international students), than students coming from any other country.

*largest* here refers to the number of international students from China　compared with other countries.

Answer (score 2):

In this context *largest source of international students* would ordinarily be understood as *source of the most international students*, not the largest country from which any international students come.